# Azure AD B2C, Graph API, and app in faulted state

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

EDIT: Issue self-resolved sometime after I opened an Azure support ticket, after I tried repeatedly to create the app. Support says they did nothing.

We need access to the Graph API, so we're trying to switch from an Azure AD B2C-registered app, to one registered in apps.dev.microsoft.com by a local B2C admin account.

The app shows up in the B2C app registrations without a problem, but it always goes immediately into a faulted state. We cannot login using the new client ID, we cannot manage the app in the Azure portal. All we can do is delete at apps.dev.microsoft.com and start over, only to repeat the process.

This occurs even if absolutely no changes are made at apps.dev.microsoft.com after the app is initially created - not even hitting the save button on the new app screen.

Comment: Is this to manage objects (i.e. users) in the Azure AD B2C directory?

Comment: It was to query objects - user's groups.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Miraculously self-resolved after opening an Azure support ticket. Support says they did nothing. This resolved after numerous attempts to delete and recreate. Suddenly, the last one started working hours after creation. The initial effort did not work after waiting overnight.

Answer (score -1):

The following document section states that B2C applications cannot be edited outside of the Azure portal: [Azure Active Directory B2C: Register your application - Faulted Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration#faulted-apps)

I attempted to replicate your issue by creating an application in the Application Registration Portal for my B2C tenant. I then viewed it in the Azure portal and had the following result:

[image]

As this app is in a faulted state it means we cannot create B2C applications outside of the Azure portal.

Comment: Actually, it says we cannot EDIT applications outside of the Azure portal.

Comment: [This blog article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureadb2c/2016/09/09/known-issue-b2c-app-mgmt/) says apps can't be created in apps.dev.microsoft.com.